# php warning -Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, yii

i installed a project edusec school management system which work on php mysql yii framework.but when we copy it root directory and run index.php on local server it give following error ? what i do ??please help me?

```
   PHP warning

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\protected\yii\framework\collections\CMap.php(288)

276      * @param array $b array to be merged from. You can specifiy additional
277      * arrays via third argument, fourth argument etc.
278      * @return array the merged array (the original arrays are not changed.)
279      * @see mergeWith
280      */
281     public static function mergeArray($a,$b)
282     {
283         $args=func_get_args();
284         $res=array_shift($args);
285         while(!empty($args))
286         {
287             $next=array_shift($args);
288             foreach($next as $k => $v)
289             {
290                 if(is_integer($k))
291                     isset($res[$k]) ? $res[]=$v : $res[$k]=$v;
292                 else if(is_array($v) && isset($res[$k]) && is_array($res[$k]))
293                     $res[$k]=self::mergeArray($res[$k],$v);
294                 else
295                     $res[$k]=$v;
296             }
297         }
298         return $res;
299     }
300 
Stack Trace
#0  
–  C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\protected\yii\framework\base\CModule.php(468): CMap::mergeArray(array("class" => "CDbConnection"), 1)
463         foreach($components as $id=>$component)
464         {
465             if($component instanceof IApplicationComponent)
466                 $this->setComponent($id,$component);
467             else if(isset($this->_componentConfig[$id]) && $merge)
468                 $this->_componentConfig[$id]=CMap::mergeArray($this->_componentConfig[$id],$component);
469             else
470                 $this->_componentConfig[$id]=$component;
471         }
472     }
473 
#1  
+  C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\protected\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(153): CModule->setComponents(array("user" => array("allowAutoLogin" => true, "class" => "RWebUser"), "phpThumb" => array("class" => "ext.EPhpThumb.EPhpThumb"), "authManager" => array("class" => "RDbAuthManager"), "urlManager" => array("urlFormat" => "path", "rules" => array("<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>" => "<controller>/view", "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>" => "<controller>/<action>", "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>" => "<controller>/<action>")), ...))
#2  
+  C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\protected\yii\framework\base\CModule.php(483): CComponent->__set("components", array("user" => array("allowAutoLogin" => true, "class" => "RWebUser"), "phpThumb" => array("class" => "ext.EPhpThumb.EPhpThumb"), "authManager" => array("class" => "RDbAuthManager"), "urlManager" => array("urlFormat" => "path", "rules" => array("<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>" => "<controller>/view", "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>" => "<controller>/<action>", "<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>" => "<controller>/<action>")), ...))
#3  
+  C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\protected\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(144): CModule->configure(array("name" => "College Management System", "preload" => array("log"), "import" => array("application.models.*", "application.extensions.jtogglecolumn.*", "application.extensions.AjaxList.AjaxList", "application.components.*", ...), "modules" => array("gii" => array("class" => "system.gii.GiiModule", "password" => "secure", "generatorPaths" => array("ext.gii-extended"), "ipFilters" => array("127.0.0.1", "::1", "192.168.0.163")), 0 => "notification", 1 => "webservice", "rights" => array("install" => false, "superuserName" => "SuperAdmin", "authenticatedName" => "Authenticated", "userIdColumn" => "user_id", ...), ...), ...))
#4  
+  C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\protected\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(127): CApplication->__construct("C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest/protected/config/main.php")
#5  
+  C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\protected\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(100): YiiBase::createApplication("CWebApplication", "C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest/protected/config/main.php")
#6  
–  C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest\index.php(18): YiiBase::createWebApplication("C:\xampp\htdocs\yiitest/protected/config/main.php")
13 
14 // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
15 defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
16 
17 require_once($yii);
18 Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
19 ?>
20
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing array to `foreach` loop

Comment: no i d't know....please tell me how we modify that error??step by step because i am new for php

Answer (score 0):

The function `array_shift()` at line 287 has returned `null`, so `$next` is not an array.
And of course `foreach()` requires an array.

Comment: but i am new ..please tell ..what i change and where??

Comment: It doesn't seem a piece of code written by a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the value before passing into the loop. This will catch when the array is empty.

```
  $next=array_shift($args);
  if ($next != null) 
  {
     foreach($next as $k => $v)
     {
        // do things here
     }
  }
```